# Find out exact file type in C#

Tags: c#, file-extension

As you know files have extensions and mime types.
but these two attributes are not intelligent enough two determine exact type of file. For example I have a `.exe` file and i rename it's extension two `.png`. So if I try to find out it's type or mime type programmatically the result will be `images/png` or `.png` but I want to read the header of file and find out exact file type. Is it possible programmatically with C# language?

**Edit**

Of course some questions are similar to mine but as you know files starts with a hex string, for example :

`"JPEG", ".jpg",  0xFF, /*0xD*/ 0xD8, 0xFF, 0xE0, null, null, 0x4A, 0x46, 0x49, 0x46, 0x00`

`"Graphics Interchange Format 87a", ".gif", 0x47, 0x49, 0x46, 0x38, 0x37, 0x6`

and etc.

Do file types have similar starting hex format?

Comment: Yes, but you should know exactly what is the content of the so called 'header' in any kind of existing file.

Comment: You probably need to limit the scope of the question; if you want to test for png particularly is well documented (spec here: http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/) so you could write a parser just for that.

Comment: Have you read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/58510/using-net-how-can-you-find-the-mime-type-of-a-file-based-on-the-file-signature, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177922/how-to-determine-file-type and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547654/determine-the-file-type-using-c-sharp?

Comment: You can check the [file type signatures.](https://gyorgybalassy.wordpress.com/2013/08/04/mime-types-sniffing-in-c-sharp/)

Comment: May be [Guessing a file type based on its content](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/85054/guessing-a-file-type-based-on-its-content) would be interesting question to have a look on

Comment: There's already some existing file format analyzers, maybe you can try its command line by C# if it has command line function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try checking for certain file signatures or magic numbers in the files. Here's the link for list of [known file signatures](http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html) and seems quite up to date:

There is another way of doing the same. Use [Winista MIME Detector](http://www.netomatix.com/Products/DocumentManagement/MimeDetector.aspx).

There is one XML file `mime-type.xml` that contains information about file types and the signatures used to identify the content type. You will need this file to create instance of `MimeTypes` object. Once you have created `MimeTypes` object, then call `GetMimeType` method to get `MimeType` of the stream. If the mime type could not be determined then a null object is returned from this method. Following code snippet demonstrates use of the library.

Example :

```
  MimeTypes g_MimeTypes = new MimeTypes("mime-types.xml");
    sbyte [] fileData = null;
    using (System.IO.FileStream srcFile = 
        new System.IO.FileStream(strFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open))
    {
        byte [] data = new byte[srcFile.Length];
        srcFile.Read(data, 0, (Int32)srcFile.Length);
        fileData = Winista.Mime.SupportUtil.ToSByteArray(data);
    }
    MimeType oMimeType = g_MimeTypes.GetMimeType(fileData);
```